# Can't load new project Unity 3D on Linux

Tags: unity3d

when i try to create new project on unity, i am stuck on this step, my new project have clicked, unity3D have message rendering package, but after that unity force close / close program.

[image: unity 3D can't load project]

Comment: Could you run Unity from Terminal and paste the output into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try **signing out and signing in** again.

I had same problem. I installed beta 5.5.1 and it worked well the first time. But later the above problem occurred.

Later I saw that I was working offline. I connected to wifi and signed in again worked well.